# Android widget WRAP_CONTENT not working

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-widget, android-bitmap

I have following widget in my app and it contains an `ImageView` with width and height set as `WRAP_CONTENT`. Root view is a `RelativeLayout` again with width and height set as `WRAP_CONTENT`.

[image]

My issue is why there are some padding (marked in black) on top and bottom of the widget? I want it to be perfectly square. Following is my widget layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_battery_2x2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_widget_arc_battery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`@dimen/widget_margin` and `@dimen/widget_padding` is zero.

`ImageView` contains a dynamically generated Bitmap (width and height is 400).

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

This is my first widget app :) I'm kinda lost and can not figure out why this extra padding is there. Anybody has an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [App Widget Design Guidelines | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

> When your widget is added, it will be stretched to occupy the minimum number of cells, horizontally and vertically, required to satisfy its minWidth and minHeight constraints.

Each device has a grid on its home screen that widgets are forcefully aligned with.  You can even see on some devices that the aspect ratio of the grid cells change when rotating between portrait and landscape.

The docs at the link above have some advice for how to specify sizes for your widgets.  Some of the information there might help you.

I would recommend that if you are only showing the `ImageView`, instead of using a `RelativeLayout`, use a `FrameLayout` with a gravity of `center` and a transparent background.  That way the `FrameLayout` might get stretched but your `ImageView` should stay square.

Even better, you might not need a `ViewGroup` subclass at all.   Just have the `ImageView` as your top level component and use a scale type of `FIT_CENTER`.  Then your bitmap should square up inside the `ImageView`. (Oh, and don't specify a background color for the `ImageView`, just do the background color in the bitmap.)

Comment: Hi Kris, Thanks for your answer. I user bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(75,0,0,0)); and it does the job. However there is a widget with more than one imageview. In that case I'm gonna need to have a root layout to wrap them all. I will try it with FramaLayout and see how it goes.